# Como faço a soma da diferença de 2 intervalos no Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Preciso fazer a soma de todas as diferenças dos intervalos que cumprirem a condição do where. Só existe um porem, se não houver end_date nessa linha, preciso pegar o horario atual e fazer o cálculo com o horário atual ao invés de end_date.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION total_paused_time (v_id Integer)
    RETURNS Interval
as $$
    DECLARE @aux integer
    select sum(@aux),
        case when end_date = null then @aux := now() - start_date 
        else then @aux := end_date - start_date 
        end
    from called_pause where called_id = v_id and internal = false;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: E qual erro você está enfrentando ?

Comment: A versão do postgreSQL que eu uso, não aceita o uso de @variavel, então estava tendo um erro de sintaxe, acabei por solucionar o problema de outra forma e publiquei a resposta abaixo.

Comment: Voce publicou um erro de sintaxe e um problema vago... e você mesmo respondeu... continua difícil de entender a utilidade disto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando `coalesce` é mais simples:

```
select sum(coalesce(end_date, now()) - start_date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver o problema. Basicamente, as condições vão dentro do sum().

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION total_paused_time (v_id Integer)
    RETURNS Interval
as $$
    select sum(
        case when end_date = null then now() - start_date
        else end_date - start_date
        end)
    from called_pause where called_id = v_id and internal = false;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Comment: Para o seu case funcionar você deveria usar `is null`: `when end_date is null`. Do jeito que está ele vai sempre executar o `else` porque nada é igual a nulo. Nem mesmo um nulo é igual a nulo.